# Multiplication table with X's while using functions?

Tags: python, function, multiplication

Comp sci student here,

Very lost on how to add those X's on a multiplication table like the added photo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdHoZ.png

How on earth would I add those X's while also using functions? Here's my code if this helps:

```
    for i in range(1,11):
        for j in range(1,11):
            print(i * j, end='\t')
        print('')
```

Comment: Use an if statement. If i and j are in the range where you want to put an x, print an x instead of a number.

Comment: Right.  `if (i > 3 or j > 3) and (i * j != 81):` / `print('x',end='\t')`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve] and update your post accordingly. Also notice pictures are very poor medium to exchange textual data copy paste instead.

Comment: Use a function to generate the product as a string. If the inputs are in certain bounds, the function returns X

Answer (score 0):

The rule for the `X` is `i>3` and `j>2` and `i*j != 81`

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        if i > 3 and j > 2 and i * j != 81:
            print('X', end='\t')
        else:
            print(i * j, end='\t')
    print()
```

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
2       4       6       8       10      12      14      16      18
3       6       9       12      15      18      21      24      27
4       8       X       X       X       X       X       X       X
5       10      X       X       X       X       X       X       X
6       12      X       X       X       X       X       X       X
7       14      X       X       X       X       X       X       X
8       16      X       X       X       X       X       X       X
9       18      X       X       X       X       X       X       81
```